# При установке PyQt5 "pip install pyqt5" происходит ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При установке PyQt5 "pip install pyqt5" происходит ошибка, версия Python 3.8.0. Другие библиотеки подключаются.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй пересоздать виртуальное окружение, нужно создать папку, затем в ней открыть командную строку, затем python -m venv venv, в рабочей папке появится папка venv, потом в командной строке: venv\scripts\activate, python -m pip install pyqt5

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!  Вообще, основная проблема была в том, что не был установлен Build Tools C++ от MS.